# Traces of a $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ function converging to boundary trace?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, trace

Today I have the following question: Say $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^d$ is open, bounded, with Lipschitz boundary. Let $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$. Then $u|_{\partial\Omega}$ is well-defined as the image of the trace operator. My main question is: if you have a sequence of $(d-1)$-dimensional "nice" sets $S_n\subset\Omega$ (nice in the Lipschitz sense) that approximate $\partial\Omega$ uniformly, does it follow that
$$
u|_{S_n}\rightarrow u|_{\partial\Omega}
$$
in the sense that
$$
\int\limits_{S_n}u\phi\,dx\rightarrow\int\limits_{\partial\Omega}u\phi\,dx
$$
for each test function $\phi\in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$, as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Think of $S_n$ as approximations of the boundary. If these approximations do not occur uniformly, but say, only in an appropriate $L_2$ sense or in an a.e. sense, does the answer to the main question change? Finally/alternatively, please give a reference to a good book/paper that discusses boundary approximations in PDE applications, if it exists.

Comment: You may have a look at Brenner&Scott, The mathematical theory of finite element methods, 3rd edition, 2008, Ch. 10.2,pp.274

Note that it is not so easy to quantify "uniform approximation" of the boundary by sets because these domains do not need to be star-shaped.

Comment: Alternatively, you may have a look at Shapes and Geometries by Delfour&Zolesio, 2011, 2nd Edition, ch. 8, where the author discuss domain approximations and convergence of solution of PDEs defined on the sequence of approximate domains. However, I warn you that this is a thick and tough book.

Comment: Thank you for the references! I will make sure to take a look at them later.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in general the answer is no. However something very close to what you want is true. Consider the case $d=2$ and $\Omega=(0,1)^2$. Then for every smooth function $u$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus you have
$$u(x,y)-u(x,0)=\int_0^y\partial_y u(x,s)\,ds.$$ By Holder's inequality,
$$|u(x,y)-u(x,0)|^2\le y\int_0^y|\partial_y u(x,s)|^2\,ds.$$
Integrate over $(0,1)\times (0,\varepsilon)$ to get
$$\int_0^\varepsilon \int_0^1|u(x,y)-u(x,0)|^2 dxdy \le \varepsilon^2 \int_0^1\int_0^\varepsilon|\partial_y u(x,s)|^2\,dsdx.$$
By continuity of the trace operator the same inequality holds for $u$  in $H^1(\Omega)$. Set $y=\varepsilon t$. Then 
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1|u(x,\varepsilon t)-u(x,0)|^2 dxdt \le \varepsilon\int_0^1\int_0^\varepsilon|\partial_y u(x,s)|^2\,dsdx.$$
Letting $\varepsilon \to 0$  you get
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_0^1 \Bigl(\int_0^1|u(x,\varepsilon t)-u(x,0)|^2 dx\Bigr)dt=0$$
Take $\varepsilon=1/n$. Then there exists a subsequence $1/n_k$ such that 
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_0^1|u(x,\frac1{n_k} t)-u(x,0)|^2 dx=0,$$ for $\mathcal{L^1}$ a.e. $t$.  This is telling you that the trace of $u$ on the segment $(0,1)\times \{\frac1{n_k} t\}$ converges in $L^2(0,1)$ to the trace of $u$ on $(0,1)\times \{0\}$ for $\mathcal{L^1}$ a.e. $t$. 
I think one can construct examples (the mystic bed of nails?) that show that this cannot happen for every $t$. 
For a general domain you can flatten the boundary locally and reduce to this case. 
I don't know a good reference for boundary approximations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! So is it correct to say that basically what I want is true on  some subsequence?

Comment: No, what is true is that you can find a sequence of nice sets for which the traces approximate the traces. But if you start with a given sequence of nice sets this may no longer be true, not even for a subsequence.